# I can't figure out what is wrong with this email code

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "test@hotmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Website boeking";

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['naam-2']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email-2']) ||
        !isset($_POST['aankomst']) ||
        !isset($_POST['vertrek']) ||
        !isset($_POST['opmerkingen'])) {
        died('Er zijn een paar fouten met je bericht! Probeer het opnieuw.');       
    }  

    $naam = $_POST['naam-2']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email-2']; // required
    $aankomst = $_POST['aankomst']; // required
    $vertrek = $_POST['vertrek']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['opmerkingen']; 

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    $email_message = "Ontvangen bericht: \n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Naam: ".clean_string($naam)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Aankomst datum: ".clean_string($aankomst)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Vertrek datum: ".clean_string($vertrek)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Bericht: \n".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-to: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

This is the PHP code I have standing in "boeking-script.php"

```
<form id="form-Boeking" name="form-Boeking" data-name="Boeking via website" method="POST" action="boeking-script.php">

<div class="form-text black">Naam *</div><input type="text" class="text-field w-input" maxlength="30" name="naam-2" data-name="naam-2" placeholder="Naam" id="Naam-2" required="">

<div class="form-text black">Email adres *</div><input type="email" class="text-field-2 w-input" maxlength="25" name="email-2" data-name="email-2" placeholder="Email adres" id="Email-adres-2" required="">

<div class="form-text black _50">Aankomst datum *</div>
<div class="form-text black _50 right">Vertrekdatum datum *</div>

<input type="text" class="text-field-2 _50 w-input" maxlength="10" name="aankomst" data-name="aankomst" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj" id="Aankomst-2" required="">
<input type="text" class="text-field-2 _50 right w-input" maxlength="10" name="vertrek" data-name="vertrek" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj" id="Vertrek" required="">

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="form-text">Eventuele opmerkingen</div><textarea id="opmerkingen" name="opmerkingen" maxlength="300" placeholder="Opmerkingen" data-name="Opmerkingen 2" class="textarea"></textarea>

<div class="height-30"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Verstuur" data-wait="Even geduld..." class="button w-button">
</form>
```

This is the form that I am using, I am using this way for the contact form as well (different files, seperated  from eachother) and it's working perfectly fine.. So I can't find out what the problem is.

P.S. I know the code is sort of messy, sorry for that

Comment: so basically what problem you are facing?

Comment: If the code "is working perfectly fine", what's the problem then?

Comment: share which type of issue you have in your code?

Comment: I am using exactly this code on a different form, with a different action="". That code is working perfectly fine but this code isn't working and it's killing me because I am stuck and I can't find the problem.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: at the end of php code you missing close bracket `}` (`if(isset($_POST['email'])) {`) you didn't closed the bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form code there is no tag with `name="email"`, so in the PHP code when you try to check if the `email` parameter is set, the code just ignore the entire code.

You should change

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['email-2'])) {
```

at the very beginning of your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I knew the problem wasn't a big one but I totally missed it. Thanks alot :)